# JSON Decoding String

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to decode a JSON string using

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('d'))
```

where d is a POST parameter containing a JSON string.

I get the following error in the stacktrace:

```
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 22 (char 22)
```

This is the JSON string:

```
{"data":{"40":{"html":"<span style=\"color:#ffffff;\">test</span>","background":"transparent"},"41":{"html":"","background":"transparent"},"42":{"html":"","background":"transparent"}},"action":"save"}
```

However it works if I dont apply the span tag in data->40->html

```
{"data":{"40":{"html":"test","background":"transparent"},"41":{"html":"","background":"transparent"},"42":{"html":"","background":"transparent"}},"action":"save"}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Where did you get the json string from? is it exactly what you get out of `request.POST.get('d'))` ?

Comment: The string comes from a Javascript array. The 'html' element of the array comes from a CKEditor instance.

Comment: I mean the string that you posted here. How did you get it? Because what you posted works fine, so I suspect that what comes out of the POST may be a little different.

Comment: And yes, the string is exactly what comes out of request.POST.get('d')

Comment: What are you doing to emulate the issue?

Comment: Ah, it appears this is something else. If I write .get('d') to the server's log the string is cut off.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is something with backslashes in the source string.

When I parse

```
"""{"data":{"40":{"html":"<span style=\"color:#ffffff;\">test</span>","background":"transparent"},"41":{"html":"","background":"transparent"},"42":{"html":"","background":"transparent"}},"action":"save"}"""
```

with json.loads(), it fails with a similar error.

However, when I disable escape sequences (r'' string literal), it works:

```
r"""{"data":{"40":{"html":"<span style=\"color:#ffffff;\">test</span>","background":"transparent"},"41":{"html":"","background":"transparent"},"42":{"html":"","background":"transparent"}},"action":"save"}"""
```

Obviously, `'\"'` in your string is being escaped and results in `'"'` when you construct the string, probably in JS(?). Haven't seen the code that builds it, but try adding an extra backslash: `'\\"'`

UPDATE: You may replace `r'\'` with `r'\\'` in a string. But it is better to understand how does the string look to begin with. When you inserted the string body into your message, where did you get it from?

Comment: The string comes from a html wysiwyg textarea

Comment: Check what happens to backslash symbols if they are entered by user. Do they become double backslashes now, without the replacement?

Comment: No they don't, but I don't think this is the issue. It appears request.POST.get('d') is being cutoff where there is a semicolon in the string.

Comment: Then try to replace a backslash with a pair of backslashes, and look at the result. Probably it will satisfy you.

Comment: Backslashes are being escaped into double backslashes, I just checked. As I said the problem seems to be semicolons. If I send {"data":"te;st"} all thats in request.POST.get('d') is: {"data":"te

Comment: Hard to say not seeing the details, since the problem is with form and JS, not with Python. Either it is encoded to JSON in a wrong way, or posted in a wrong way. Apparently the problem can not be solved at server side.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that is the string you're getting?  It works for me:

```
>>> ss = r'{"data":{"40":{"html":"<span style=\"color:#ffffff;\">test</span>","background":"transparent"},"41":{"html":"","background":"transparent"},"42":{"html":"","background":"transparent"}},"action":"save"}'
>>> json.loads(ss)
{u'action': u'save', u'data': {u'42': {u'html': u'', u'background': u'transparent'}, u'40': {u'html': u'<span style="color:#ffffff;">test</span>', u'background': u'transparent'}, u'41': {u'html': u'', u'background': u'transparent'}}}
```

Notice that I used a raw string for `ss` because otherwise `\"` will just be replaced by `"` in the string resulting in `'"<span style="color:#ffffff;">test</span>"'` which doesn't work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Ah ok, that sounds like the problem. How can I convert a variable into a raw string?

Comment: To make a string "raw" you just prefix it with `r`:  `r"this is a raw string"`.  `"this is not a raw string"`.  This doesn't work with "variables" if that's what your asking though:  `foo = "bar"; rbar #doesn't make bar a raw string`

Comment: Have you printed request.POST.get('d') before inserting it into your message? It is necessary to understand what exactly it contains. Probably it is enough to replace r'\' with r'\\' in it.

Comment: The html comes from a user input textarea so the problem with replacing r'\' with r'\\' is that if a user explicitly types '\' it will get replaced with '\\'..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for us:

```
json.loads(request.POST.get('d').encode('string-escape'))
```